# What is the definition of affine independence then?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, affine-geometry, matroids, algebraic-combinatorics

The following is the definition of affine dependence (This definition is from James Oxley book, second edition "matroid theory")

**Definition of affine dependence:**

A multiset $\{ \underline{v_1},\dots, \underline{v_k} \},$ the members of which are in $V(m, \mathbb F)$ ( the vector space of dim. m over the field $\mathbb F$), is affinely dependent if $k \geq 1$ and there are elements $a_1, a_2, \dots ,a_k$ of $\mathbb F$ that are not all zero such that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i v_i = 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i = 0.$ A multiset of elements from $V(m, \mathbb F)$ is affinely independent if it is not affinely dependent.

**My question is:**

What is the definition of affine independence then? How it deals with this condition $\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i = 0.$ Could someone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition is that the only solution of $\sum a_iv_i=0$ and $\sum a_i=0$ is the trivial one $a_i=0$, all $i$.

You can check that $v_1,\dots,v_k$ form an affinely (in)dependent set if and only if $v_2-v_1,\dots,v_k-v_1$ form a linearly (in)dependent set. The condition holds subtracting any $v_j$ rather than $v_1$.